# .htaccess rewrite and remove .php on only a few files

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite all my .php file extensions to /

And I got it to work wit this code:

RewriteEngine On

```
# hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

However, It breaks my admin pages that are talking to the database for example pages that have code and use the URL break:

create-ticket.php?device=XBOX+360

I need to leave the extension on a a couple pages...

Is there a way I can use the above code but only on specific files and not every file that ends with .php?

Thanks,
-O

Comment: You could exclude certain files or folders, or use a query parameter to pass the page so it establishes a pattern to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do exclusion like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(create-ticket|admin)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```